# Check if Validation InputTitle or InputMessage is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a UserForm for adding comments to specific cells on Worksheet. I was using another Worksheet to store comments before. However now I have figured out that I can get values from Validation InputTitle and InputMessage directly.

My question is how I can check for "if Validation InputTitle or InputMessage is empty" separately for each one?

I have tried the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton28_Click()

    On Error Resume Next
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Validation.InputTitle
    Me.TextBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Validation.InputMessage
    
End Sub
```

However this is updating only my first box (TextBox1) and TextBox2 have values even if `Validation.InputMessage` is empty.

I have also tried:

```
Private Sub CommandButton28_Click()
    
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Validation.InputTitle) Then
        Me.TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Validation.InputTitle
    End If
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Validation.InputMessage) Then
        Me.TextBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Validation.InputMessage
    End If
    
End Sub
```

This does not even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Validation.InputTitle) Then
        Me.TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Validation.InputTitle
    End If
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Validation.InputMessage) Then
        Me.TextBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Validation.InputMessage
    End If
```

with

```
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Validation.InputTitle) Then
        Me.TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Validation.InputTitle
    Else
        Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
    End If
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Validation.InputMessage) Then
        Me.TextBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Validation.InputMessage
    Else
        Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

```
Private Sub CommandButton28_Click()
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
    
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Validation.InputTitle
    Me.TextBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Validation.InputMessage
    
End Sub
```